# Use generic functionality to perform api calls using rxjava in combination with flat map operator

Tags: generics, retrofit, rx-java2, flatmap

My api service interface:

```
Observable <PlanResponse> getPlansRx(@Query string)
        (
                @Header("session-token") String session_token

        );
```

My ApiCall using Rxjava:

```
private < T extends BaseResponse > void execute( Function<T,Observable> function, ArrayList < T > arrayList, final IHttpCallBack< T > serverResponseCallBack ){
 Observable.fromIterable(arrayList)
                .flatMap(s->
                        function.apply(s)
                ).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Observer<T>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSubscribe ( @NonNull Disposable d ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext (T t ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError ( @NonNull Throwable e ) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onComplete ( ) {

                    }
                });
    }
```

}

Actually when I want to create an Api Call using this method I dont know how to pass my Api service interface as a parameter to my Api call method because I must call this method with the ArrayList elements as parameter but as you can see it is done inside the executeRx method and inside flatMap.what should I do?

```
      public void getPlans(ArrayList< Object > allCcPlans,  IHttpCallBack < PlanResponse > serverResponseCallBack ){
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            Function function = (Function) instance.getApi().getPlansRx("?");
           instance.executeRx(function,allCcPlans,serverResponseCallBack);
        }
    }
```

What sould I put instead of the question mark?

the reason that I insist on creating this method is to create a generic method for all my multi parallel requests.